# How to write Java 8 Consumer to work with Collection(Map) of Consumer

Tags: interface, java-8, consumer

I have list of Java Consumers in java which I am maintaining in a HashMap, but when I am calling accept method, the arguments is coming null.

```
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;
    Map<String, Consumer<String>> daoMethodMap = new HashMap<>();

    daoMethodMap.put("CLASS1", ( serializedRecord ) -> {
            try
            {
                Class1 class1Obj = objectMapper.readValue(serializedRecord, Class1.class);
                Class1Dao.insertClass1Instance(class1Obj);
            }
            catch( Exception e )
            {
                throw new RuntimeExeption(e);
            }

        });

        daoMethodMap.put("CLASS2", ( serializedRecord ) -> {
            try
            {
                Class2 class2Obj = objectMapper.readValue(serializedRecord, Class2.class);
                Class2Dao.insertClass2Instance(class2Obj);
            }
            catch( Exception e )
            {
                throw new RuntimeExeption(e);
            }

        });

        daoMethodMap.put("CLASS3", ( serializedRecord ) -> {
            try
            {
                Class3 class3Obj = objectMapper.readValue(serializedRecord, Class3.class);
                Class3Dao.insertClass3Instance(class3Obj);
            }
            catch( Exception e )
            {
                throw new RuntimeExeption(e);
            }

        });
```

And when I call any of the Consumer, the argument in the Consumer seems having nothing so I get the reconstructed object using objectmapper having all properties as null values. Do you guys has any idea ?

This is how I call Consumer-

```
Consumer<String> daoMethod = daoMethodMap.get("CLASS1");
String record = "{\"prop1\":\"val1\", \"prop2\":\"val2\"}";
daoMethod.accept(record);
```

**And at Consumer, I get class1Obj having value of prop1 and prop2 as null.**

Comment: Did you try running this without the Consumers? (i.e. just `Class1 class1Obj = objectMapper.readValue("{\"prop1\":\"val1\", \"prop2\":\"val2\"}", Class1.class);
                Class1Dao.insertClass1Instance(class1Obj);`). I don't think the Consumer has anything to do with your problem.

Comment: Its probably the mapping thats incorrect.

Comment: So you get prop1 & prop2 as key values in your consumer::accept function. Then Consumer is working fine, something else must be missing.