# How to put a consumer in a map in Kotlin?

Tags: list, kotlin, consumer, mutablemap

I come from java and I'm new in kotlin.
I was trying to create a map and put a consumer inside as in these examples:

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44422685/consumert-mapped-classt-in-hashmap](https://stackoverflow.com)

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46464820/how-to-write-java-8-consumer-to-work-with-collectionmap-of-consumer](https://stackoverflow.com)

but using kotlin.
So far I haven't done it successfully.

Here is an example of my code:

```
val map = mutableMapOf<T, Consumer<List<T>>>()

 map.put(type, (list) -> {
      repository.save(doMappingToOtherEntity(it))
    })
```

But "list" is in red and everything in "{...}" is in grey

Do you know if what I'm trying to do is possible in Kotlin? If it is, what I'm doing wrong? and if it's not possible, what other alternative would you suggest?

Thanks!

EDIT: I realized the code provided is not correct so here it is:

```
val map = mutableMapOf<T, Consumer<List<T>>>()

 map.put(type, (list) -> {
      repository.save(doMappingToOtherEntity(list))
    })
```

Comment: If you need your map to be generic "per-item", so each item has its own T, then this is not supported by the standard map in neither Kotlin nor Java. You have to create a heterogeneous typesafe map as explained in questions provided by you. Or simply use 'Any' and do unsafe casts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you tried to use just this:

```
map[type] = Consumer { list ->
    repository.save(doMappingToOtherEntity(it))
}
```

[**Full example.**](http://tpcg.io/_XYA9A8)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the full example! It helped me to adapt it to my specific case. I think it works! I will have to check then with the test, but so far I don't see the errors I saw before in the code.

Comment: I did the tests and it worked. Thanks again!